# Is it possible to add an ArrayList of array to a file?

Tags: java, file, object, arraylist, jtable

I'm sorry if it is a stupid question, but I've been thinking on it for more than 5 days, reading Documentation and googling, but I haven't found the answer for this, and how to use it into a code (I mean example), too much blah blah and let's go to the problem:

My question is, as the title says: **Is it possible to add an ArrayList of array to a file?**

if so, I have these codes (SSCCE):

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.io.*;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import javax.swing.table.*;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.util.*;
class create_study_list{
public static JFrame his;
public static JRadioButton ka, si, on, kun;
public static ButtonGroup tipo;
public static JPanel botones, botarr, botaba, tipos;
public static JButton agreg, canc, selec, deselec;
public static JTable table;
public static TableColumn column;
public static DefaultTableModel model;
public static JScrollPane scroll;
public static DefaultTableCellRenderer r, r2;
public static kanji k;
public static ArrayList<kanji> lista_estudio=new ArrayList<kanji>();
public static void agregar(){
    kanji aux = new kanji();
    String nombre = "nombre";
    for(int j=0; j<10; j++){
        aux.set_unicode((String)table.getValueAt(j,1), j);
        aux.set_significado((String)table.getValueAt(j,2), j);
        aux.set_onyomi((String)table.getValueAt(j,3), j);
        aux.set_kunyomi((String)table.getValueAt(j,4), j);
        aux.set_agregar((boolean)table.getValueAt(j,5), j);
        aux.set_tipo(1);
    }
    lista_estudio.add(aux);
    try{
        ObjectOutputStream out=new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("study_list_kanji.txt"));
        out.writeObject(lista_estudio);
        out.close();
    }
    catch(Exception exp){
    }
}
public static void main(String args[]){

    ka = new JRadioButton("Kanji");
    si = new JRadioButton("Significado");
    on = new JRadioButton("Onyomi");
    kun = new JRadioButton("Kunyomi");
    tipo = new ButtonGroup();

    k = new kanji();
    his = new JFrame("Creacion de Listas de Estudio");
    agreg = new JButton("Agregar seleccionados");
    canc = new JButton("Cancelar");
    selec = new JButton("Seleccionar todos");
    deselec = new JButton("No seleccionar nada");
    table = new JTable();
    column = null;
    model = new DefaultTableModel(k.get_data(), k.get_header());
    tipos = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER));
    botones = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
    botarr = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.TRAILING));
    botaba = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER));
    tipo.add(ka);
    tipo.add(si);
    tipo.add(on);
    tipo.add(kun);
    tipos.add(ka);
    tipos.add(si);
    tipos.add(on);
    tipos.add(kun);
    botarr.add(deselec);
    botarr.add(selec);
    botaba.add(canc);
    botaba.add(agreg);
    botones.add(tipos, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    botones.add(botarr, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    botones.add(botaba, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    agreg.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            agregar();
        }
    });
    r = new DefaultTableCellRenderer() {
        @Override
        public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
            super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);
            setForeground(Color.blue);
            setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
            setFont(new Font("Microsoft JhengHei", Font.BOLD, 50));
            return this;
        }
    };
    r2 = new DefaultTableCellRenderer() {
        @Override
        public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
            super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);
            setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
            setFont(new Font("Microsoft JhengHei", Font.BOLD, 13));
            return this;
        }
    };
    table.setFont(new Font("Microsoft JhengHei", Font.BOLD, 13));       
    table = new JTable(model){
        @Override
        public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int col){
            switch(col){
                case 0:
                    return false;
                case 1:
                    return false;
                case 2:
                    return false;
                case 3:
                    return false;
                case 4:
                    return false;
                case 5:
                    return true;
                default:
                    return false;
            }
        }
        @Override
        public Class getColumnClass(int column) {
            switch (column) {
                case 0:
                    return String.class;
                case 1:
                    return String.class;
                case 2:
                    return String.class;
                case 3:
                    return String.class;
                case 4:
                    return String.class;
                case 5:
                    return Boolean.class;
                default:
                    return Boolean.class;
            }
        }
    };

    table.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setCellRenderer(r2);
    table.getColumnModel().getColumn(1).setCellRenderer(r);
    table.getColumnModel().getColumn(2).setCellRenderer(r2);
    table.getColumnModel().getColumn(3).setCellRenderer(r2);
    table.getColumnModel().getColumn(4).setCellRenderer(r2);

    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        column = table.getColumnModel().getColumn(i);
        switch(i){
            case 0:
                column.setMinWidth(35);
                column.setMaxWidth(35);
                break;
            case 1:
                column.setMinWidth(60);
                column.setMaxWidth(60);
                break;
            case 2:
                column.setMinWidth(100);
                column.setPreferredWidth(400);
                break;
            case 3:
                column.setMinWidth(125);
                column.setPreferredWidth(395);
                break;
            case 4:
                column.setMinWidth(250);
                column.setPreferredWidth(400);
                break;
            case 5:
                column.setMinWidth(50);
                column.setMaxWidth(50);
                break;
            default:
                column.setPreferredWidth(875);
                break;
        }
    }
    table.setRowHeight(table.getRowHeight()+70);
    table.setModel(model);
    table.getTableHeader().setReorderingAllowed(false);

    his.add(table, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    his.add(botones, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    his.add(table.getTableHeader(), BorderLayout.NORTH);
    scroll = new JScrollPane(table);
    his.add(scroll);
    his.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    his.setTitle("Lista de Kanji");
    his.setSize(1350, 700);
    his.setResizable(false);
    his.setVisible(true);
    his.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

}
}
```

And I have this other code, which is needed in the upper code:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.io.*;
class kanji{
String unicode[];
String significado[];
String onyomi[];
String kunyomi[];
boolean agregar[];
int i, tipo;

kanji(){
    unicode = new String[200];
    significado = new String[200];
    onyomi = new String[200];
    kunyomi = new String[200];
    agregar = new boolean[200];
    i = 0;
    tipo = 0;
}
int get_tipo(){
    return tipo;
}
void set_tipo(int t){
    this.tipo = t;
}
String []get_unicode(){
    unicode = new String[]{
        "\u4e00",
        "\u4e8c",
        "\u4e09",
        "\u56db",
        "\u4e94",
        "\u516d",
        "\u4e03",
        "\u516b",
        "\u4e5d",
        "\u5341"
    };
    return unicode;
}
String []get_significado(){
    significado = new String[]{
        "Uno, 1",
        "Dos, 2",
        "Tres, 3",
        "Cuatro, 4",
        "Cinco, 5",
        "Seis, 6",
        "Siete, 7",
        "Ocho, 8",
        "Nueve, 9",
        "Diez, 10",
    };
    return significado;
}
String []get_onyomi(){
    onyomi = new String[]{
        "ICHI, ITSU",
        "NI, JI",
        "SAN, JOU",
        "SHI",
        "GO",
        "ROKU, RIKU",
        "SHICHI",
        "HACHI",
        "KYUU, KU",
        "JUU, JITTSU, JUTTSU",
    };
    return onyomi;
}
String []get_kunyomi(){
    kunyomi = new String[]{
        "hito, hito(tsu)",
        "futa, futa(tsu), futata(bi)",
        "mi, mi(tsu), mitt(tsu)",
        "yo, yo(tsu), yot(tsu), yon",
        "itsu, itsu(tsu)",
        "mu, mu(tsu), mut(tsu), mui",
        "nana, nana(tsu), nano",
        "ya, ya(tsu), yat(tsu), you",
        "kokono, kokono(tsu)",
        "too, to",
    };
    return kunyomi;
}
boolean []get_agregar(){
    agregar = new boolean[]{
        true,
        true,
        true,
        true,
        true,
        true,
        true,
        true,
        true,
        true,
    };
    return agregar;
}
void set_agregar(boolean agre, int p){
    this.i = p;
    this.agregar[i] = agre;
}
void set_unicode(String uni, int q){
    this.i = q;
    this.unicode[i] = uni;
}
void set_significado(String sig, int r){
    this.i = r;
    this.significado[i] = sig;
}
void set_onyomi(String ony, int s){
    this.i = s;
    this.onyomi[s] = ony;
}
void set_kunyomi(String kuny, int t){
    this.i = t;
    this.kunyomi[i] = kuny;
}
Object [][]get_data(){
    Object data[][] = new Object[10][6];
    String uni[] = new String [10];
    String sig[] = new String [10];
    String on[] = new String [10];
    String kun[] = new String [10];
    boolean agre[] = new boolean [10];
    uni = get_unicode();
    sig = get_significado();
    on = get_onyomi();
    kun = get_kunyomi();
    agre = get_agregar();
    for(int k=0; k<10; k++){
        data[k][0] = k+1;
        data[k][1] = uni[k];
        data[k][2] = sig[k];
        data[k][3] = on[k];
        data[k][4] = kun[k];
        data[k][5] = agre[k];
    }
    return data;
}
String []get_header(){
    String header2 [] = new String[]{"#", "KANJI", "SIGNIFICADO", "LECTURA ON", "LECTURA KUN", "Agregar"};
    return header2;
}
}
```

When I save my file "study_list_kanji.txt" what happens? am I saving 10 Objects of 1 element each or am I saving 1 object of 10 elements? and whenever I press 'agreg' will it override my objects or will it save new ones?

Or how could I save 1 object of 10 elements.

I'll later use those objects into a JList, and I'll read each object into another file to "print" their elements into JLabel...

Comment: FYI, the first "S" in SSCCE stands for "short".

Comment: it's the shorter I could make it... my real classes are 380 and 723 lines, these ones are 203 and 149 lines... I'm sorry about it

Comment: *"if so, I have these codes (SSCCE): .. And I have this other code, which is needed in the upper code:"*  That code should be included in the end of the source for the other file.  An SSCCE is ***1*** source file by definition.  Tips:  I note you set column widths on the table.  Is the same problem still present when you *don't* do that?  If so, it is not necessary for the SSCCE..

Comment: The short answer to your question is yes, it is possible to write an ArrayList of an Array to a file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are writng one object of 10 elements to the file. So when you read you will get back an Arraylist object back. as mentioned in the previous answers you have to implement 
Kanji implements Serializable to save.
for reading you can do like this.

```
    private static ArrayList<Kanji> readFile() {
    ArrayList<Kanji> kanjis = null;
    try {
        ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(
                "study_list_kanji.txt"));
        while (true) {
            try {
                try {
                    kanjis = ((ArrayList<Kanji>) in.readObject());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } catch (EOFException e) {
                return kanjis;
            }
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return kanjis;
}
```

> put this in your main method you may need to iterate over the array to get all lements in the array

```
    ArrayList<Kanji> kanjis = readFile();
    if (kanjis != null) {
        for (Kanji kanji : kanjis) {
            System.out.println("kunyomi:  " + kanji.get_kunyomi()[0]);
            System.out.println("onyomi:  " + kanji.get_onyomi()[0]);
            System.out.println("significado:  "
                    + kanji.get_significado()[0]);
            System.out.println("unicode:  " + kanji.get_unicode()[0]);
        }
    }
```

> Hope this will help

Comment: So, this code at the end will print all the elements of the 1st object, am I right?

If I want to print the 2nd object elements I must change [0] for [1] and so on...?

Answer (score 0):

Your `kanji` class should implement `Serializable` interface. In the implementation, you define the manner how `kanji` encode its content to a stream and how `kanji` decode content from a stream.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to use Java's Serialization tools to perform this however it will not produce a readable file. If that is not the case then check out this tutorial http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_serialization.htm which has examples of Serialization, and Deserialization. However if you prefer to have something readable then perhaps think about writing the elements of the array a line separated by a comma, and each new line is an entry in the arraylist. Hope it helps a little.

Comment: which "tutorial" are you talking about?